# Main window won't change

Tags: interface

I recently downloaded blender to do some video editing. I was playing around with it and everything was going well. The next day when I opened Blender I couldn't navigate away from the starting screen. The top menu bar will change but that is pretty much it. I tried reinstalling but that didn't work. In the screen grab you can see I'm in movie clip editor (or at least I should be).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Simply change that top toolbar back to ***Info***.  That's the default for Blender.  From there you have all the traditional menus.  From the Info bar, you can select your preferred Workspace.  You can use the ***Motion Tracking*** Workspace which is already setup with three ***Movie Clip Editor*** panes or you can create your own custom Workspace:

[image]

As far as I know, the top bar is the only one you cannot pull down down into a pane (like all the other panes):

[image]

Comment: Actually the movie clip editor they are trying to use is in the motion tracking screen.

Comment: @sambler - You're right, I shouldn't have answered this so late.  Edited.